# What role does this to-infinitive phrase play among adjective, adverb? And what does it modify in this sentence?

Tags: to-infinitive

Below is a sentence you can see in **Control Panel\All Control Panel Items\Ease of Access Center** in Windows.

> You can use the tools in this section **to help you get started**.

If that sentence alone doesn't seem to make much sense, then please look at the screenshot below.
[image: Screenshot of EaseOfAccessCenter in Windows 10]

I wonder which **"to help you get started"** modifies in that sentence. Is it an adjective phrase that modifies the noun **"the tools"**? Or is it an adverbial phrase that makes the sentence mean "You can use the tools in this section so that you can help yourself get started."?

Comment: What does _'if you're using Windows 10'_. mean? Does it mean that If I use some different kind of OP (IOS, Windows 8.2..) I'm not able to answer your question? Please revise or amplify your question, each phrase it isn't clear

Comment: @Max Did that expression make confusion? I meant literarily I can see that sentence on my laptop the OS version of which is Windows 10. Since I have only one computer, I don't know whether it is the same in other versions of Windows. :)

Comment: The Windows 10 phrase did not create any confusion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *You can use the tools in this section [to help you get started].*

It’s not an adjective or an adverb; it's a **purpose adjunct**: it gives the purpose of using the tools.

Adjuncts like this are modifiers in clause structure; in this case it modifies the preceding  verb phrase "can use the tools in this section".

Syntactically, it can be preceded by "in order", which is a sure indication that the clause is a purpose adjunct. And it can be moved to front position as only adjuncts can:

*[To help you get started], you can use the tools in this section*.

Comment: Thank you for answering very much. :) If then, why is it not __"to help yourself get started""__ instead of __"to help you get started"__?

Comment: @SmartHumanism That rule normally applies when the antecedent and the pronoun are related to the same verb. But here, the first "you" is related to "can use" while the second "you" is related to a different verb, i.e. "help" You could use the reflexive "yourself" if you wished, but it would be purely for emphasis, which isn't really needed here.

Comment: Thank you. If I alter that sentence into a sentence like following - "You can help you/yourself get started by using the tools in this section.", is using "yourself" a must?

Comment: @SmartHumanism Yes, it is a must.

Answer (score 1):

> You can *use this knife* to cut the bread.
>
> You can *use my phone* to call your office.
>
> You can *chant this magic spell* to wake the dead.
>
> The chicken *crossed the road* to get to the other side.
>
> He *climbed the ladder* to get onto the roof.
>
> He *left early* to get to work on time.
>
> He *saved some of the food* to eat later.
>
> He *was sent to prison* to pay for his crimes.
>
> He *was sent to bed without supper* to teach him a lesson.

I would say that the infinitive clause complements the verb phrase (the verb, adverb, and any direct object) in the prior clause.

Comment: Thank you @TRomao very much for the comment and answering. But I wonder why it is "to help you get started" instead of "to help yourself get started". I have been taught in school that in sentences that the subject and the object are the same person then the object has to be in "myself/yourself/herself/himself/themselves/" form.

Comment: But the subject and the object are not the same.  Using the tools helps you get started.

Comment: Thank you @TRomano. But I wondered about it because anyway the person who eventually will do "using the tools" is "you" in the sentence "You can use the tools in this section to help you get started.". So I thought the semantic subject would be "you", not "using the tools".